# How to check if the user typed "yes" string

Tags: c++, string

I want to see if the user typed "yes" (which has been assigned to yes string variable)

```
string yes = "yes";
if (yes == "yes")
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Haven't you just answered your own question?

Comment: I guess your real question is "How to get user input", right?

Answer (score 4):

Either with what you have (`operator ==`) or with the `compare` function.

To let the user input the string, you can use `std::cin >> yes`.

Answer (score 3):

```
  if (yes.compare("yes") == 0) { /* indeed yes */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just compare the `yes` 'string to the literal `"yes"` as others have said.  I believe it is important to allow for users entering upper case or mixed case.  I think programs should be flexible (within reason) with users.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string> 

std::string yes = "Yes"; 
std::transform(yes.begin(), yes.end(), yes.begin(), ::tolower);
if (yes == "yes")
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: I find it useful, too, but this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I would do it this way - it's an answer I think. Maybe I phrased it wrong.

Comment: You are somehow correct ... it indeed answers the original question with a method of comparison.